# Count not working on RDD - Python, Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

Problem: I m currently trying to read in a text file with Json data. The aim of this is to count the distinct number of users by the userID present in the Json.
Issue at hand: Applying count() on an RDD in python spark throwing error attached.

> zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
>     to the final reduce call

Code:

Step 1: i read in the file into an RDD called rdd_step1 using

```
sc.textFile('filepath')
```

Step 2: create a function that basically reads each line and returns a Json object if its a valid data set.

```
def safe_parse(raw_json):
    try:
        jo = json.loads(raw_json)
        if jo.get('created_at'):
            return jo
        else:
            None
    except:
        return None
```

Step 3: I create a intermediate rdd where i parse the strings and get json objects to create a (key,value) rdd

```
rdd_step2 = rdd_step2.map( lambda x: safe_parse(x)).filter(lambda x: x is not None).map(lambda x: (x['user']['id_str'],1))
```

Step 4: Use reduce by Key and get the counts

```
counts=     rdd_step2.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
Count = counts.count()
print(Count)
```

sample data:
{"TS":"Mon jan 1 00:00:00","id":"123213","text":"Apparently you aren't allowed to have an anti","user":{"id":4494956854,"id_str":"4494956854","name":"Amy Smalley","screen_name":"amyjosmalley","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Stay-at-home mom ","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":11,"friends_count":40,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":116,"statuses_count":23,"created_at":"Tue Dec 15 18:57:57 +0000 2015"}}

Full error message:

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 #raise NotImplementedError()
>         5 counts=     rdd_step2.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
>   ----> 6 Count = counts.count()
>         7 print(Count)
>         8 #my_output.append("num-unique-users", users_count)
>
> C:/Users/srikanth/Downloads/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py
>   in count(self)    1071         3    1072         """
>   -> 1073         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()    1074     1075     def stats(self):
>
> C:/Users/srikanth/Downloads/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py
>   in sum(self)    1062         6.0    1063         """
>   -> 1064         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)    1065     1066     def count(self):
>
> C:/Users/srikanth/Downloads/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py
>   in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
>       933         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
>       934         # to the final reduce call
>   --> 935         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
>       936         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
>       937
>
> C:/Users/srikanth/Downloads/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py
>   in collect(self)
>       832         """
>       833         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
>   --> 834             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
>       835         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
>       836
>
> ~\Downloads\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1255         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> ~\Downloads\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       329             else:
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 1 in stage 417.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   1.0 in stage 417.0 (TID 462, localhost, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\srikanth\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-f7a58081-572f-4ea9-a53e-a84f5ebfb955\0c\temp_shuffle_36ab37dd-0f30-41c6-8f4f-ef1400d58ba8
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\srikanth\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-f7a58081-572f-4ea9-a53e-a84f5ebfb955\0c\temp_shuffle_36ab37dd-0f30-41c6-8f4f-ef1400d58ba8
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     ... 1 more

Comment: Can you show some sample json data?

Comment: Standard twitter API data:  {"TS":"Mon jan 1 00:00:00","id":"123213","text":"Apparently you aren't allowed to have an anti","user":{"id":4494956854,"id_str":"4494956854","name":"Amy Smalley","screen_name":"amyjosmalley","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Stay-at-home mom ","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":11,"friends_count":40,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":116,"statuses_count":23,"created_at":"Tue Dec 15 18:57:57 +0000 2015"}}